# Bound UDP socket not closed when network becomes unavailable

Tags: sockets, rust, udp

On Linux, I open an UDP socket and bind it to an address that is currently available. I then listen in a loop for new packets. Then I disable wifi, the interface goes down and the network address is removed from the interface. I would expect the receive call to return an error but this is not the case.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to receive an error from a call to receive when the address the socket is bound to disappears?

Example code in Rust:

```rust
use std::net::UdpSocket;

fn main() {
    let mut socket = UdpSocket::bind("192.168.2.43:64041").expect("Unable to open socket");
    loop {
        let mut buf = [0u8; 1500];
        match socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
            Ok((n, _addr)) => println!("Received {} bytes", n),
            Err(err) => println!("Error receiving bytes: {}", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only person who closes sockets is you, the application. If you had connected the socket you would get an ICMP_UNREACH error when *sending*, but you get nothing on receive.

Comment: Also, UDP is not a connected protocol.